# ZFS raidz1 - Where did my storage space go?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, zfs

I have a `raidz1` pool with 3 disks of 12 TB each.

Now with single parity, wouldn't that mean I have about 24 TB of total space?

```
$ zfs list -o space -r pool

NAME                   AVAIL   USED  USEDSNAP  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  USEDCHILD
pool                   6,44T  11,1T        0B    128K             0B      11,1T
pool/backup            6,44T   999G        0B    999G             0B         0B
pool/download          6,44T   811G      128K    811G             0B         0B
pool/download@seed         -   128K         -       -              -          -
pool/old               6,44T   657G        0B    657G             0B         0B
pool/work              6,44T  5,34T        0B   5,34T             0B         0B
pool/documents         6,44T  1,27T        0B   1,27T             0B         0B
pool/etc               6,44T  28,3G        0B   10,8G             0B      17,5G
```

Looks like I have 17.5 TB. Seems like a pretty steep 'rounding error' to me. Is this right?

```
$ zpool status
  pool: pool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    pool              ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0        ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST10xxx   ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST10xxx   ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST10xxx   ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Is there some command I can use to see if the entire disk is being used?

---

I need about 10TB to temporary store some server data while the fs is being updated. I thought I had it, but then I actually checked.

Comment: Are you sure that the disks are 12TB? From the availabe storage space and also from the disk names ST10xxxx, this looks rather like 10TB disks.